# android:@Theme.Translucent Locks orientation to Portrait?

Tags: android, styles

I've created a new style to set the background as transparent,  but for some reason ever since the app doesn't change layout to landscape when device is rotated.
  Should I specify something in the new style ?

Here is it's code :

```
< style name="Transparent" parent="android:@Theme.Translucent">
    < item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually kinda solved it apparently the orientation is according to the background app in case of transparent background, since i kept testing when the Launcher in the back, i always got portrait only.

Comment: Well, just using a different activity behind it doesn't really solve the problem. What if you have an activity on top of the launcher, that is translucent and you want to rotate? screenOrientation=sensor is a bad solution because it ignores the user's screen lock.

Answer (score 16):

While you are not specify [android:screenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) for activty, android uses 
`"unspecified"` default value, which means that the system chooses the orientation.

In a case you are using style with `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`, system selects an orientation based on the orientation of underlying activity in stack. So it's hard to get your application in landscape mode, because most of launchers fixed to portrait.

Just set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` for all Translucent activities to force it choose orientation independently:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    ...>
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: I have `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for the background activity. So when I set `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` for foreground translucent activity and rotate to landscape my background activity also rotates despite the fact that it has `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. How can I force background activity to keep its portrait even though foreground is in landscape mode?

Answer (score -1):

just right in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Ippin_NewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: No change ...  Looks like the android:@Theme.Translucent is the cause of the orientation lock

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687712/activity-should-be-transparent-but-has-black-background check it out

Comment: I actually kinda solved it  apparently the orientation is according to the background app in case of transparent background, since i kept testing when the Launcher in the back, i always got portrait only.